# Bad Key Exception using RSACryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa

The key exchange method is: RSA-PKCS1-KeyEx

So I don't think the answers in other similar questions apply and I have no control over the certificate - it's valid and is supposed to work.

.NET Framework 3.5

The code:

```
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key;
        byte[] bytestodecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(SignatureValue);
        byte[] plainbytes = rsa.Decrypt(bytestodecrypt, false);
```

Screenshot of the attributes of the rsa object:

[image]

Comment: How was the signature generated?

Comment: If you have a problem with your code, then you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem. Help us help you without wasting time on guessing.

Comment: Since this is about a signature, `RSACryptoServiceProvider#Decrypt` is a wrong method for that. You need to use `RSACryptoServiceProvider#VerifyData`.

Comment: The "signature" is a digital signature made go of a set of strings in a particular order.  This string is SHA-1 encoded then the hash is encrypted using a private key.  The encrypted signature and the data items are passed to me along with the x509 certificate.  Then I am to string the other fields together then SHA1 encode it and then decrypt the hash passed using the private key in the certificate and compare the hashes.  I just can't decrypt the hash with the public key in the certificate because of the bad key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While RSA can do both signatures and encryption, they can't be used interchangeably (except for at the raw/"no padding" version of the algorithm, which .NET does not support; and even then the keys are "backwards").

The signature blob is computed by "encrypting" with the private key.  It gets "decrypted" by the public key, and then the underlying system compares it with the provided hash and hash algorithm.  If they both match, it returns true; otherwise it returns false (or might throw an exception if it gets really confused).

So rather than `rsa.Decrypt(signature, false)` you want `rsa.VerifyHash(hash, signature, hashAlgorithm, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1)`, which returns a bool.

The "bad key" exception is because you only have a public key (which is sufficient for verify) but called decrypt (which requires the private key).

Comment: This is the answer to the problem I stated.  I still have issues with generating a hash of the signature fields that matches what the provider is computing but I'll work through that.